# Is it possible to make a patch file which takes into account new files and will create them?

Tags: linux, bash, diff, patch

Suppose I have two directories, `A` and `B` and each of them have `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. If I go and modify `file2.txt` a bit I can then run a recursive `diff -u` to generate a patch, and I would then be able to say `cd A && patch < thepatch.patch A` and apply those changes to the contents of `A`. But what if, in making modifications to `B`, I also create a new file `file3.txt`. How can I get a patch which, when applied to `A` will fill in the missing files?

Right now, the output of just running a `diff` for a missing file says `Only in B: file3.txt`

Comment: Mike's answer below answers your question perfectly.  But I worry you're asking the wrong question.  If you're dealing with a tree of text files and trying to track changes between them, that sounds like a job better suited to a SCM like git than low level tools like diff/patch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass `diff` the `-N` or `--new-file` switch, it will treat non-existent files as empty.  With this, the contents of new files will show up in your diff and the files will be generated by `patch`.